# Can't get Flash Builder 4.6 debugger to run

Tags: flash, apache-flex, debugging, air, flash-builder

I've tried everything, firewalls, reinstalling etc etc. I can't get the debugger to connect no matter what I do.

I'm just writing a simple Air application, with Flex and Actionscript. But any type of debugging on any type of application doesn't work. I get this message

The Flash Builder debugger failed to connect to the running application.

[image: Initial Error]

Then often when I try again, I get this message

Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind

[image: Secondary Error]

Running the program without debugging works fine.

Comment: Do you have a different version of the Java runtime in your path, ahead of Flash Builder's JVM?

Comment: Not really sure, I echo'd %path% and I have no jvm in there. Where should I be looking?

Comment: Silly question, but assuming you have the debug Flash player installed? :)

Comment: I do, but perhaps I'll remove it and reinstall, I downloaded all the versions that made sense, though, its an AIR app so I wasnt clear which I needed.

Comment: Besides assuring your debug launch configuration is setup correctly, I would assume this means the port is already being used by another server socket.

Comment: Its a standard install it should work.

Comment: Since this is an AIR App, you shouldn't need the Flash Player Debugger.  I added the "AIR" tag tot his question.  But, have no idea what the cause is; I've never had problems w/ AIR.

Comment: Not sure if this will do the trick, but what if it's a local permissions issue.  Maybe run Flash Builder 4.6 with administrator privileges?  Not giving this as the answer, because i'm not confident enough this would solve your problem.  I haven't worked with AIR yet.

Comment: Doesnt help, already running it as an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending way too much time on this and trying everything suggested and more, the solution unfortunately was to reformat the laptop and try again.

Thanks for everyone for their responses and efforts.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this indicates that the tcp connection between ADL and Flash Builder could not be established using port 7935 because the socket is in use.

Use `netstat` to assure the port is not in use.

Comment: If I do a plain and simple netstat there is nothing showing on 7935. If I attempt to debug a web app it crashes flash player.

Comment: Can you run ADL from a command line to verify it is functional?  C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\bin\adl.exe

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with it to know all the command line options to try

Comment: adl myApp-app.xml  Have you tried running Flash Builder as administrator?  Turning off anti-virus?  Is this project migrated?  Have you tried importing the project to a new workspace?  Validate the app xml?  Did you fully uninstall Flash Builder 4.5 and install 4.6 with iOS options?

Comment: when I run adl as you said it says "Initial content not found". I have uninstalled / reinstalled, I have tried in a new workspace. I dont know how to validate the app.xml however I cant debug a new app with a single button. So its not the app. I've tried turning firewall off also.

Comment: Is this standalone Flash Builder or part of a CS suite?  Did you fully uninstall Flash Builder 4.5 and Apple iOS Devices, then install Flash Builder 4.6?  Are you using the default SDK?  adl "initial content" is a xml tag that Flash Builder auto-generates at compile time.  You could enter the path of your swf.  Have you tried remotely connecting to a debug?

Comment: Yes I've uninstalled everything, its standalone. Although I have CS installed also. I've spent way too much time on this and no closer. All the things that should work dont. Something strange on my system, last resort is to reformat the thing.

Comment: Flash Builder 4.6 cannot be installed side by side Flash Builder 4.5.  If Flash Builder 4.5 or Apple iOS Devices is installed in your CS suite, it must be uninstalled for you to use Flash Builder 4.6.

Comment: Ive uninstalled the complete CS thinking this was the issue. It didn't help. I've since reinstalled CS. So I just went uninstalled FB 4.5 from CS, and uninstalled / reinstalled 4.6 still doesn't work. the ADL seems to be crashing.

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same situation, and resolve it with http://therush.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/resolved-flex-builder-3-debugger-stopped-working/

It seems a very strange bug.
I solve it with:

1. Close FB4.6
2. Launch a Web Application HTML with Flash content (content must have been built with debug enabled)
3. Right click, select Debugger, Select "Localhost" (or "Other Machine", input 127.0.0.1), click Connect
4. Needn't care about if the connection is successful.
5. Close Browser, re-launch FB4.6, open your AIR application, Debug, -- the problem is gone.

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered the same issue in OSX. I resolved it by reinstalling the debugger version of flash player for mac, and changing the flash player browser to Safari in the Flex preferences.

[image]

Comment: Also fixed it for me on Win7

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I found something.

The guy at this link [Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind in Flash Builder](http://retrocade.net/news/74/unrecognized-windows-socket-error-0-jvm-bind-in-flash-builder) has a workaround. Problem is you have to do it everytime. He suggests using [TCPView](http://downloads.sysinternals.com/Files/TCPView.zip) to see and close opened connections that are using the same port as the debugger.

People in this thread [http://forums.adobe.com/message/653125](http://%27Unrecognized%20Windows%20Sockets%20error%27%20message) also notes that an old version of NOD32 was causing the problem.

---

ORIGNAL ANSWER :

The second error you get clearly indicate a problem with the Java Virutal Machine (JVM). I don't think it's project related at all.

Try checking out installed JREs (Java runtime environments) in Flash Builder.

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java - > Installed JREs
```

Check if there's anything strange here, like unknown JREs. You should use "Adobe Flash Builder 4.6", typically located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6". If it's not here add it (Add, Next, paste corresponding path) and restart Flash Builder.

If it's already there, you might want to redownload Flex 4.6 SDK and replace your current one (typically located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks").

It's unclear if you have uninstalled Flash Builder or not but if that's not the case and the above solutions doesn't work I'd considered reinstalling it from scratch.

Comment: Jason must be right then, must be a problem with the connection socket.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I'm using Google Chrome as my default browser, and although I had flash debugger installed (both IE and the "other browsers" version), I got this error.

I opened mozilla firefox and set that as default browser. Now I re-opened FB, and the error was gone.

I think this has to do with Google Chrome having flash build internally which might be slightly off.

Answer (score 1):

If your default browser is Chrome, you must set the default Flash plugin before debugger starts to work.

- In Chrome goto address: chrome://plugins/
- Click the [+]Details button at the right top side of the list.
- Find the Adobe Flash Player from the plugins list and disable internal ones.

Answer (score 0):

I was going absolutely nuts dealing with this and what one of the members above said worked for me.  Close FB, then set Firefox as your default browser open FB, change the debugger preferences to Default browser, then try debugging again, that did it for me.  I'm running FB 4.6 with firefox 17.01

Answer (score 0):

I've closed chrome web browser. Then I can execute the debugger without that msg. I suspect some tab used that port.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me just now, it happened after closing a debug Air app right after it launched. I had to restart the pc, problem solved.